# python3 priorityqueue size by priority?

Tags: python, python-3.x, queue, priority-queue

is there a way to take the .size() of the priority queue ... for each priority level?

say i have an object, which i will put in a priority queue, with a priority based on the state of some_variable ...

```
q = PriorityQueue()

if some_variable:
    q.put((1, my_object))
else:
    q.put((2, my_object))
```

can i then find out, by asking for some kind of .qsize() method, such as a variant maybe of...

```
q.qsize()
```

but instead of the total size of the queue, i'd like to know the size for each of the two separate 'groups'/priorities (qsize where priority==1, qsize where priority==2), in this case.

as opposed to just the total q.qsize()?  hopefully that makes sense.

Comment: I don't think you use the queue correctly. You want to `q.put((1, my_object))`, not `q.put(1, my_object)`. An item is expected to be a tuple of the priority and the actual payload. Also, method `q.qsize()` is not reliable.

Comment: sry i transcribed the code without the extra set of parens that make the tuple - you are right about that - (fixing...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest way I can see to do this would be

```
from collections import Counter
sizeByPriority = Counter(priority for priority, _elem in q.queue)
```

but of course this requires iterating over the entire queue, which may be prohibitive in your situation, and probably isn't thread-safe.

Comment: This definitely gets me closer to being able to do and explore what I wanted to.  Thank you!  One followup question.  Do I need to instantiate the Counter object every time I add items to my queue (because, if I instantiate it just once, won't it only know the state of the q.queue at the time it's instantiated?).

Comment: Yeah, the counter doesn't change automatically. If it becomes too expensive to rebuild it whenever you need it you might consider updating it every time you add something to the queue or remove something from it. That might get tricky depending on your architecture though.